# how to find the range for x for which the equation holds

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inverse-function

[image]

how to find the value of x for which the equation holds?

Comment: Well, solving the equation for x will give you the values of x for which the equation holds..
What have you tried? Can you show your effort?

Comment: I just cant understand where to start from I checked my textbooks but they havent mentioned anything

Comment: I tried to calculate it using geometry, but I'm not sure I'm correct - do you have an answer key? I got x=1. If that is indeed the answer I'll do my best to explain how I got it.

Comment: The place to start is $$\tan(2\theta) = \frac{2\tan(\theta)}{1 - \tan^2(\theta)}.$$

Comment: @user2661923 i am not able to move further ahead can you elaborate the answer

Comment: mathSE protocol doesn't allow me to elaborate unless you edit your query to show work;  it doesn't matter whether your work solves the problem, you simply have to try.  I think that I have given you enough to try.  See also [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).

Comment: @user2661923 as a hint can you tell me what the next step could be because i am really stuck over here.

Comment: Suppose $\alpha = \tan^{-1}(x)$, and $\beta = \cos^{-1}\frac{1-x^2}{1+x^2}.$  Then $2\alpha = \beta.$  Using the formula that I gave you, what is $\tan(2\alpha)$?  Now imagine an angle whose tangent is $\tan(2\alpha)$ and whose cosine is $\cos(\beta).$  What are the sides of the triangle?  Then, solve for $x$ using the pythagorean theorem.

Comment: I am still unsure about how to construct a triangle using this.

Comment: @uriyaba the answer is x>=0

Comment: see my answer..

Answer (score 1):

You have $\tan(\alpha) = x~$ and $~\cos(\beta) = \frac{1-x^2}{1+x^2}~$ with $2\alpha = \beta.$

Using the formula from my comment,

$$\tan(\beta) = \tan(2\alpha) = \frac{2x}{1-x^2} \implies
\sin(\beta) = \tan(\beta)\times\cos(\beta) = \frac{2x}{1+x^2}.$$

Now use the pythagorean theorem to obtain a constraint on $x$.

$$\sin^2(\beta) + \cos^2(\beta) = 1 \implies
\frac{4x^2}{1 + 2x^2 + x^4} + \frac{1 - 2x^2 + x^4}{1 + 2x^2 + x^4} = 1.$$

Clearly, this equation holds **for any value of** $x$.

Now **contrast** the question in your query's title with the question that you posed in your query.  Presumably, the intended answer is that the equation holds for any value of $x$.  Therefore, the *allowable range* of $x$ is **any real number**.

**Addendum**
Responding to the OP's latest comment.

First, consider $x = -1 \implies \alpha = (-\pi/4) \implies \beta = (-\pi/2) \implies 0 = \cos(\beta) = \frac{1 - [-1]^2}{1 + [-1]^2}.$

Therefore, the **math** clearly works.

However, if your book has adopted the arbitrary convention that the *domain* of the Arccosine function is $[0,\pi]$, then the sine of $\beta$ is **not permitted** to be negative.

Therefore, since $~\sin(\beta) = \frac{2x}{1+x^2},~$the only way to satisfy the arbitrary convention is to insist that $x$ be non-negative.

Comment: But the book says its valid for only  non negative values of x for eg when x is -1 the equation does not equate

Comment: @ParvezPatel see the addendum to my answer.

Comment: so whats the derivation when sine β is not permitted to be negative.

Comment: @ParvezPatel My posted answer, including my Addendum, is the exact derivation.  First, you demonstrate that the math holds for any real value of $x$.  Then, you observe that the arbitrary constraint on the domain of the ArcCosine function outlaws negative values of $x$.